# Visual Studio Project Installers - Can these just package assemblies and not build them

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, devenv, vdproj

I am trying to make some modifications to our build processes which ensure that our vdproj files do not execute builds, they just package already build DLL's from a given location.

Is there any way to do that using configuration settings to devenv.exe? Something like:

`devenv /Project WebInstaller /Build Release /UseExistingDLLSFromHere "C:\DLLs"?`

I'm aware I could use WIX to be more flexible, but unfortunately it's a legacy installer which we have to maintain.

Regards,
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Project Output references with File references if your DLLs are being built by an external process.

I haven't found a reliable way of switching the path of File references based on the configuration though, other than modifying the vdproj in my build script.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, have you got an example of how to modify, my vdproj knowledge is minimal at best.

Comment: I'd use the IDE to add file references to your release DLLs. For debug builds, a script should then look for lines containing "SourcePath" in the vdproj.